# Best way to compare group characteristics

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, baseline

I have a dataset (say N=200) of which a subset (N=150) have undergone a certain assay.  I want to be able to say that the subgroup N=150 is not significantly different from the entire population (N=200).  Is there a way to compare the two eg in terms of baseline characteristics.  I tried comparing the N= 150 who have the assay with N=50 who do not have the assay (eg with ttests and chi square tests).  However, for one variable (blood pressure), the difference between the N=150 and N=50 group was significant, however on visual inspection the value for the N=150 did not look very different from the N=200.  Is there a way to compare the N=150 subgroup to the N=200 dataset rather than compare the N=150 and N=50 subgroups of the N=200.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "assay?"

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this article should give you the answer and the answer is usually no: https://academic.oup.com/jpubhealth/article/28/3/278/1515986?login=false